# Как ВКонтакте, Twitter и другие сервисы генерируют страницы?

Tags: python, шаблоны, javascript, html

У почти у всех социальных гигантов переход на другую страницу происходит без перезагрузки. Для этого они делают запрос, в ответ на который приходит шаблон страницы и данные. Однако когда только пользователь открывает страницу они возвращают уже собранную страницу из шаблона, при этом возвращая так же ее шаблон и данные. Неужели они дублируют код страницы отдаваемой сервером и шаблоны которые отдаются javascript'у? Или есть какой то шаблонизатор способный генерировать шаблоны как для javascript'а так и для серверной части? Если кто знает такие библиотеки для python поделитесь.

Comment: Github относится к таким ресурсам? Когда начинаешь просматривать сорцы, то путь меняется в адресной строке, а на странице перезагружается только код

Comment: [Вот пример использования шаблонов на jQuery](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112843/).

[Здесь примеры для jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html). Не обращайте внимание на Mobile - вам же никто не мешает использовать его на десктопе. Мы вроде как используем именно этот подход.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вопрос это довольно таки обширный.

Конечно, дублировать код страницы неэффективно с точки зрения затрат на поддержку проекта. В общем случае, всегда стараются избежать любого дублирования кода и контента.

В простейшем случае обновлять всю страницу нет необходимости вообще. У сервера запрашивается лишь "сырая" информация в виде JSON / XML и на текущей странице заменяются соответствующие значения атрибутов или содержимого тегов.

В случае, когда нужно заменять большую часть контента (переход на другую страницу без перезагрузки, например), стараются повторно использовать шаблоны. Шаблоны либо запрашиваются однократно при первом использовании, либо уже внедрены в JavaScript и загружены вместе со страницей.

Могу предложить вам посмотреть на шаблонизатор [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/). Он имеет реализации для большинства используемых языков, включая Python, JavaScript и CoffeeScript. Для более глубокого изучения темы предлагаю для начала вот это – [Интерактивные сайты](http://www.insight-it.ru/interactive/). В частности, вот это – [Повторное использование шаблонов](http://www.insight-it.ru/programmirovanie/javascript/povtornoe-ispolzovanie-shablonov/).

Comment: Проблема остается в шаблонизаторе. Как вообще гуглить такие шаблонизаторы вроде mustache. Хотелось бы наследование шаблонов

Comment: На первый вопрос не могу ответить - я о некоторых просто знаю: из статей, RSS и т.п. По поводу наследования - mustache умеет partials (включение одного в другой).

Answer (score 2):

Есть некоторые фреймворки/библиотеки для создания универсальных (isomorphic) приложений, где "рендерить" может и клиент и сервер. Например, [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux).

Гуглить в сторону "Изоморфное Приложение с React и Redux"